# diff between total odd and even digit of number with python

Tags: python-3.x

can be the possible diff between total odd digit and even digit of any number in python 3 with lambda.

```
ex. 
   number=13245
   odd=1+3+5
   even=2+4
   diff=abs(odd-even)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this maybe:

```
difference = abs(sum(map(lambda x: x if x%2 == 0 else -x, [int(i) for i in str(12345)])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Naïve solution, I'm sure it could be done in a better way by someone more Pythonic, but it does answer your question:

```
>>> x = 13245
>>> abs(sum([int(n) * (1 if n in ['1','3','5','7','9'] else -1) for n in str(x)]))
3
```